# Rails not launching web page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have just started to learn Ruby on Rails and in going through a tutorial I am not able to launch the rails project because of the following error.

```
-e:4:in `load': no such file to load -- script/server (LoadError)
from -e:4:in `<main>'
```

I have installed Ruby 1.9.2 and using RadRails as the IDE for creating and executing the Rails project. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely your tutorial refers to Rails 2 (for which given command works), while you're using Rails 3.

I'm not sure how exactly you start server in Rails 3 (**edit** see answer by **jdl**), but take my adice: find another tutorial. Otherwise, you'll have to create such questions here several times a day :)

Comment: +1 for "Find a new tutorial".  Or install Rails 2.3.11, but really find a new tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

If you just installed the latest Rails the the command has changed (as of Rails 3) to:

`$ ./script/rails server`

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to start a server in Rails 3 is to run this command from the root of the project:

```
rails server
```

You should have the `rails` executable in your path if you've installed the Rails 3 gem.